# How to write Inline JavaScript in ADF

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

I have a humantask view page. In one of the inputText field I would like the input text file to not except non numerical values. I have followed the link; https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/march2011-otn-harvest-351896.pdf -> page 18. Here I have the following code in my inputText field.

```
<af:inputText value="#{bindings.IBANDiger.inputValue}"
        label="#{bindings.IBANDiger.hints.label}"
        required="true"
        rendered="#{fn:startsWith(bindings.HesapGrubu.inputValue, 'S')}"
        columns="#{bindings.IBANDiger.hints.displayWidth}"
        maximumLength="#{bindings.IBANDiger.hints.precision}"
        shortDesc="#{bindings.IBANDiger.hints.tooltip}"
        id="it5">
    <af:validateRegExp pattern="[0-9]"/>
    <f:validator binding="#{bindings.IBANDiger.validator}"/>
    <af:clientListener method="suppressCharacterInput" type="keyPress"/>
</af:inputText>
```

As a source I have the following.

```
<af:resource type="javascript">
//Allow numbers, cursor control keys and delete keys
function suppressCharacterInput(evt) {
    var _keyCode = evt.getKeyCode();
    var _filterField = evt.getCurrentTarget();
    var _oldValue = _filterField.getValue();
    if (!((_keyCode < 57) || (_keyCode > 96 && _keyCode < 105))) {
        _filterField.setValue(_oldValue);
        evt.cancel();
    }
}
</af:resource>
```

In jdeveloper,  57<  is colored in red and When I save the file, it tells me that part as illagal token.

Am I missing something, or if it is not the best practise to work with javascript, what other options do I have?

Note: When I use the following, it doesn't throw error. Though it doesn't work

```
<af:inputText value="#{bindings.IBANDiger.inputValue}"
        label="#{bindings.IBANDiger.hints.label}"
        required="true"
        rendered="#{fn:startsWith(bindings.HesapGrubu.inputValue, 'S')}"
        columns="#{bindings.IBANDiger.hints.displayWidth}"
        maximumLength="#{bindings.IBANDiger.hints.precision}"
        shortDesc="#{bindings.IBANDiger.hints.tooltip}"
        id="it5">
    <af:validateRegExp pattern="[0-9]"/>
    <f:validator binding="#{bindings.IBANDiger.validator}"/>
    <af:clientListener method="sayHello" type="keyPress"/>
</af:inputText>
```

As a source I have the following.

```
   <af:resource type="javascript">
   function sayHello()
   {
     alert("Hello, world!")
   }
   </af:resource>
 </source>
```

Thanks.

Also: How do I modify the binding's. I couldn't go to the location. It has been two days, so I am new.

Answer (score 0):

> In jdeveloper, 57< is colored in red and When I save the file, it tells me that part as illagal token.

`<` symbol is html closing tag, that's why it's causing troubles.
If simplified, here's what you did: `<tag>a < b</tag>`.
Escape `<` symbol using `&lt;`: `<tag>a &lt; b</tag>`.

You can read more about html symbols escaping [on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML).